# Paypal IPN to update 'units sold' on website

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Sorry for the very basic nature of the question, but I've been searching for two days and I'm still not sure how to do this.

I've got a paypal cart/store set up. How do I leverage either paypal IPN or a third party service to identify one specific item of the three items I have for sale, and send me a notification that a copy has been purchased, and then update a counter on my original website?

Again, just suggestions or a guideline would be greatly appreciated - even to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic guideline for you:

- have a sandbox account (I assume you already do)
- create there a seller and buyer account
- set IPN setting for seller account to your testing URL (where you will be checking for certain data returned)
- for the URL mentioned above create a php file with IPN validator
- and go here https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables#id08CTB0S055Z to check variables you will be searching for.

I assume you would need to pick `num_cart_items` and loop throug possible `item_nameX` variables returned.

You don't need to code anything to validate IPN, use some of these classes:
http://www.micahcarrick.com/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2249-PHP-Process-Paypal-payment-interactions.html

Comment: Seem to be making headway! Thank you for your answer. I'll add an edit if I make it.

Comment: I have an [IPN solution](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-paypal-ipn-template/), too, that's very popular on X.com.  You can be up and running within a couple of minutes and it'll log all of your IPN data to MySQL as well as send you an email with the RAW IPN data (optionally).  It also gives you a basic web-based admin panel to browse all the IPN data.